# Convert multiple dictionaries in a list to multiple dictionaries in python

Tags: python

Update: I was able to modify the object return type. Updating the same below.

How can I convert this:

```
{
  'student_details': [
    {
      'name': 'abc',
      'state': 'CA',
      'Country': 'USA',
      'Status': 'Citizen'
    }
  ],
  'findResource': {
    'new_student_details': [
      {
        'name': 'def',
        'state': 'NY',
        'Country': 'USA',
        'Status': 'Citizen'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

into this format in python?

```
{
  'student_details': {
    {
      'name': 'abc',
      'state': 'CA',
      'Country': 'USA',
      'Status': 'Citizen'
    }
  },
  'findResource': {
    'new_student_details': {
      {
        'name': 'def',
        'state': 'NY',
        'Country': 'USA',
        'Status': 'Citizen'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your comments and solutions in advance.

Comment: What is the difference between the 2?

Comment: @Prats They're trying to convert an array of dicts into a keyless dict of dicts.

Comment: @STOPIMACODER A keyless dict of dicts is a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Comment: @WasiMaster Wait i thought you can't insert a dict into a set? its mutable so it can't be hashed right? wouldn't that be incorrect description of a set? Maybe i'm wrong

Comment: @STOPIMACODER Thanks for the heads up and giving me the benefit of the doubt. But in fact I was the person that was wrong, not you. I've made a mistake and I apologize for that. What you said in fact, was correct, and I was wrong. I didn't think at all when commenting and just sent the comment. If you tried to insert a dict into a set it would raise `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`. You were right, I was wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Dictionary is mutable, so it can't be hashed and inserted into a set. Only immutable value can be hashed.

But you can do this, althouth it isn't clear why you need a set of dictionaries at all

```
>>> import frozendict
>>> set((frozendict.frozendict(map) for map in L))
{frozendict.frozendict({'name': 'abc', 'state': 'CA', 'country': 'USA', 'status': 'Citizen'}), frozendict.frozendict({'name': 'def', 'state': 'NY', 'country': 'USA', 'status': 'Citizen'})}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to update the above response object to below:

{
  'student_details': [
    {
      'name': 'abc',
      'state': 'CA',
      'Country': 'USA',
      'Status': 'Citizen'
    }
  ],
  'findResource': {
    'new_student_details': [
      {
        'name': 'def',
        'state': 'NY',
        'Country': 'USA',
        'Status': 'Citizen'
      }
    ]
  }
}

I just need to convert '[', ']' to '{', '}'.

Comment: @Jessica What you're saying is *"I just need to do something you already told me is impossible"*.

Comment: You can't just convert "[" to "{". Because in this case "{" denote a set. All values in the set must be HASHABLE. therefore they must be IMMUTABLE.  Dictionary is not immutable.
Depending on what you need you can 
1) use frozendict
2) get rid of one "{" - use 
  'student_details': { 'name': 'abc',... instead of 'student_details': {{ 'name': 'abc',...
3) if you just need write/send this somewhere (i.e as a string) - write serializer. With serializer you can get such string

Comment: If it's 3), I hope that that recipient somewhere can actually handle that. Otherwise we might have someone else posting tomorrow, asking one of those "how do I parse this" questions :-). Probably 2) is what they should do.